# Place sum beneath each column in range in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have code that will clear everything below the "----" on a spreadsheet full of data. The "----"comes from an export into excel and I don't want data located under it, so I clear it.
After the code clears everything underneath the "----", I want to sum each column in a range and then place each column total underneath its column of data. The column range is  F  thru T. I'd like to be able to change this range in the code for other projects.
The row may not be the same each time, so the code must sum the columns after the last row of data.
Can anyone help with this, thanks!

```
Sub Remove_everything_under()

 Dim mtch As Long
    mtch = 0
    
    On Error Resume Next
        mtch = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("----", ActiveSheet.Range("A:A"), 0) + 0
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    If mtch > 0 Then
        ActiveSheet.Range("A" & mtch, ActiveSheet.cells(Rows.Count, Columns.Count)).ClearContents
    End If


End Sub
```

Comment: The code in your question has nothing to do with what you're actually trying to do (?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Sum-up Variable Sized Column Ranges

**Description**

- Adjust the values in the constants section.
- You can easily rewrite the procedure to use some of the constants as arguments for multi-purpose use.
- The following will sum up the columns defined by `cAddress` and put the results (sums) to the cells below each non-empty column range. Executing it again will double the previous result each next time.

**Some Challenges**

- `Sum` will fail if an error value so the cells of the column range have to be looped through. Solved.
- `Sum` will sum up date values. Not solved, but not an issue when looping.
- The loop will sum up `TRUE` as -1. Solved, but not an issue when `Sum` is used.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub sumupVariableSizedColumnRanges()
    
    Const cAddress As String = "F:T" ' Columns Address
    Const FirstRow As Long = 2 ' First Row
    Const hasDates_Slow As Boolean = True ' If 'True', then loop always.
    
    Dim frOffset As Long: frOffset = FirstRow - 1 ' First Row Offset
    
    Dim rg As Range ' Initial Range: from FirstRow to last worksheet row.
    With ActiveSheet.Columns(cAddress)
        Set rg = .Resize(.Rows.Count - frOffset).Offset(frOffset)
        'Debug.Print "Initial Range address = " & rg.Address(0, 0)
    End With
    
    Dim crg As Range ' Column Range
    Dim rrg As Range ' Result Range
    Dim lCell As Range ' Last Cell (Range)
    Dim cError As Long ' Current Error Number
    Dim Result As Double ' Result
    
    ' If error, then loop.
    Dim Data As Variant ' Data Array
    Dim cValue As Variant ' Current Value
    Dim r As Long ' Data Array Rows Counter
    
    ' Starting idea if same last row for all columns:
'    Set lCell = rg.Find("*", , xlFormulas, , xlByRows, xlPrevious)
'    If lCell Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
'    Set rg = rg.Resize(lCell.Row - frOffset)
'    Debug.Print "Processing Range address = " & rg.Address(0, 0)
    
    For Each crg In rg.Columns
        Set lCell = crg.Find("*", , xlFormulas, , , xlPrevious)
        If Not lCell Is Nothing Then
            Set rrg = crg.Resize(lCell.Row - frOffset)
            'Debug.Print "Current Range address = " & rrg.Address(0, 0)
            If hasDates_Slow Then
                cError = -1 ' Dates are not summed up.
            Else
                On Error Resume Next ' Sum 'fails' if error values.
                Result = Application.Sum(rrg) ' Dates are also summed up.
                cError = Err.Number
                On Error GoTo 0
            End If
            If cError <> 0 Then
                'Debug.Print "Current Error Number  = " & cError
                cError = 0
                Result = 0
                If rrg.Rows.Count = 1 Then
                    ReDim Data(1 To 1, 1 To 1): Data = rrg.Value
                Else
                    Data = rrg.Value
                End If
                For r = 1 To UBound(Data, 1)
                    cValue = Data(r, 1)
                    If IsNumeric(cValue) Then
                        If VarType(cValue) <> vbBoolean Then ' exclude TRUE = -1
                            Result = Result + cValue
                        End If
                    End If
                Next r
                Erase Data
            End If
            lCell.Offset(1).Value = Result
            Set lCell = Nothing
        End If
    Next crg

End Sub
```